# How to properly manage Realm instances

Tags: java, multithreading, dependency-injection, realm, dagger-hilt

I have a Java Hilt project, and I want to call my Realm repository from any class. The problem is Realm instances can only be accessed by the thread that created them, and I have multiple threads using Realm.

The workaround I implemented is using multiple instances of Realm. I don't think it is the correct way to do it.

Is there any possibility to have a shared Realm instance? Or maybe making Hilt manage it?

The error I've faced:

> Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed
> on the thread they were created.

Comment: *multiple instances of Realm* - That's not the correct way of doing it and we don't know what - *i have multiple threads using Realm* - means or why that's being done. You can pass objects between threads using Realm but again, without  knowing the use case we won't be able to assist. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)